# align content to center without using width

Tags: html, css

I need to center the contents but if I don't set the width it is not working. I would love to set width but the problem with that is on larger monitors it runs fine but when I try it on a smaller monitor the left column goes to top and the center column below it and the same thing to right column. So how do I center using `margin:0 auto` but not specifying the width?

```
<div class="mainwrap">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="centerContent"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.mainwrap{

 margin:0 auto;
 }   
.left{
vertical-align:top;

 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:30px;

 width:250px;

 }
.centerContent{
padding-top:20px;
display:inline-block;
 width:800px;
 margin:0px;
 background-color:#F7F7F7;
 border:1px solid #C0C0C0;

  }
.right{

display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:blue;
width:200px;

}
```

Comment: There are couple ways to get rid of this. using `%` dimensions, combination of `%` and `px`, using CSS float for left/right columns and `margin-left` and `margin-right` for the centered one. And even using CSS media queries.

Comment: Wait, setting the width makes it wrap on smaller monitors? Setting the width should *prevent* it from wrapping on smaller monitors - although horizontal scrolling is arguably no better. Did you try setting the width in pixels, or as a percentage of the parent?

Comment: I did try setting the width both in px and % percentage, if I get the smaller screen to be centered the larger one will be centered to left. If I increase the width it will go to the center but again the smaller screen doesn't center.

Comment: can you make a fiddle that shows what the problem is? and maybe a picture of what you want it to look like? all i see is 3 divs stacked, and i'm not sure what you are trying to make

Comment: @user2510039 Here is a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/eviqet/1). You should use `min-width` and `width` property together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it bt using `display: table;` on the parent div. You'd need to float the items to get them how you want

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/jPLUK/

General example

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/jPLUK/1/

Answer (score -1):

try add

```
 text-align:center;
```

to the wrap

you could also consider setting the width to be in % so it will scale regardless of the screen resolution

Comment: `text-align:center;` messes up the contents inside the three Divs and yes I did set the width with percentage like 71% which is fine on large screen but doesn't work on smaller one

Answer (score -1):

You are using .right class twice, probably is the problem, try this code instead.

```
<div class="mainwrap">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="centerContent"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```